# Legendre Polynomial relation

Tags: legendre-polynomials

Show that $$\Sigma_{r=0}^{n}(2r+1)P_r(x)=P_{n+1}'(x)+P_n'(x).$$

I've started with the relation $$P_l'(x)=\Sigma_{r=0}^{\frac{1}{2}(l-1)}(2l-4r-1)P_{l-2r-1}(x).$$
I tried adding the sums for $P_n'(x)$ and $P_{n+1}'(x)$ to show that this is equal to the first expression, but that didn't get me anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: That can be proved also by exploiting the fact that Legendre polynomials give an orthogonal base of $(-1,1)$ with respect to the standard inner product. It is enough to compute $$\int_{-1}^{1} P_m'(x)P_r(x)\,dx$$ for $m\in\{n,n+1\}$ and $r\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler: [Bonnet's recursion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Additional_properties_of_Legendre_polynomials) gives

$$ (2n+1) P_n(x) = P_{n+1}'(x)-P_{n-1}'(x) $$
hence the given sum is a telescopic sum.

Comment: Much easier than proving it yourself:)